# Quickfix engine handling empty tags issues

Tags: quickfix

We are using quickfix engine version 1.14.3 , it looks like empty tags in messages can be handled using config parameter ValidateFieldsHaveValues=N , but looks like instead of this being set, message gets rejected. Is this a known bug with the version ? Or how can i test what is going wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the messages, including the reject.

Comment: Looks like this is the exact bug i am facing https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/issues/464

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier But i see i have DataDictionary field defined in DEFAULT section and then UseDataDictionary=N in session section. I am new to this but i understanding is since DataDictionary is defined already in default section, I am using it , can i mark UseDataDictionary=Y probably in session section ?

Comment: **You are not using QuickFIX/n.**  1.14.3 is a QuickFIX-for-C++ version number.

Comment: QuickFIX for C++ is on version 1.15.1.  It's possible this issue has been fixed already.  Unfortunately that project has dropped their C# wrapper support because QuickFIX/n is a better native C# solution.